# Plot decimal degree Latitude longitude in an XY coordinates(meters)

Tags: latitude-longitude, location-services, cartesian-coordinates

I have a set of Lat-long values of various locations on the map.
Eg.

(18.605906724686033, 73.14103329678608)
(18.606069075261992, 73.13979277511669)
(18.606066194308486, 73.13996845980716)
(18.60624633887108, 73.1400100340469)

I need to plot them in a graph (in meters) with the first position as the origin.
Please help me with the formulae for the conversion.
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x0= 18.605906724686033      //origin longitude

y0= 73.14103329678608      //origin latitude

x1= 18.606069075261992     //longidute

y1= 73.13979277511669     //latitude

dlong=x1-x2

dlat=y1-y2.

x=dlong*111139.         //the x-cordinate for the given longitude

y=dlat*111190         //The y-cordinate for the given latitude